# How the conditional random fields algorithm work?

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, natural-language-processing, markov-chains

Im searching about conditional random fields for a long time and cant understand the concepts of this algorithm.

I understood markov chains, and understood that conditional random field is a more complex modification of markov chain, Im right?

So, what is the best didactic explanation of conditional random fields?

Comment: There are probably many textbooks that explain CRFs.  Which one is the "best" is a subjective question.  Why don't you pick a textbook or tutorial and try reading through it?  Then if you have a question about a specific aspect you are stuck with, you can try asking that.  However, asking for an overview of an entire subject like this is too broad (it's asking too much to expect someone to write that in a question, and there's little point in duplicating standard resources), and asking us to recommend a text is probably too subjective to work well here.

Comment: its not like I didn't searched anything and tried to learn, is because Im very frustrated with this subject.  The explanations I found about this algorithm I cant understand and I am in the last year of my cs degree, its very frustrating situation. If you can help me indicating textbook with better didactic explanations would be the best :D

Comment: I hear your frustration.  However, only certain kinds of questions are suitable here.  I don't understand.  Have you searched?  Have you found *any* textbook that explains this?  What have you read so far?  There are two ways you could make this a suitable question: (1) after reading about CRFs, ask a specific question about some specific aspect you don't understand; (2) possibly, ask for a book that meets certain objectively-evaluable criteria that you spell out in the question (but you can't ask for "best", and you'll need to tell us what books you've considered and why you rejected them).

Comment: Ok, i will try to do that, thanks man